# Cannot read property 'value' of null on simple var assignment: var goToThis = "";

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a javascript error Cannot read property 'value' of null on simple var assignment var goToThis = "";

[image: Chrome Developer Tools show the code here]

```js
// It is the second function that has the error.

function nextFocus(tLast) {
    var goToThis = "";
    var val = 0;
    if(tLast === 'activity') {
        if(document.getElementById('[Slip]Note').value === "") {
            document.getElementById('[Slip]Note').value = document.getElementById('[Slip]Activity').value;
        }
     }
    
    if((tLast === 'activity') && (fLedes === true)){
        document.getElementById('[Slip]Task No').focus();
    } else  if((tLast === 'activity') && (fLedes === false)){
        goToThis = 'billableHrs';
    } else if(tLast === 'expense'){
        goToThis = 'priceAdjustment';
    } else if((tLast === 'task') && (initialSlipType === 'time')){
        goToThis = 'billableHrs';
    } else if((tLast === 'task') && (initialSlipType === 'expense')){
        goToThis = 'priceAdjustment';
    }
    
    if(goToThis === 'billableHrs') {
        val = getReal(document.getElementById("[Slip]Billable Hrs"));
        if(val === 0) {
            document.getElementById("[Slip]Billable Hrs").value = '';
            //alert('[Slip]Billable Hrs: '+val);
        }
        document.getElementById('[Slip]Billable Hrs').focus();
    } else if (goToThis === 'priceAdjustment') {
        val = getReal(document.getElementById("[Slip]Price Adjustment"));
        if(val === 0) {
            document.getElementById("[Slip]Price Adjustment").value = '';
            //alert('[Slip]Price Adjustment: '+val);
        }
        document.getElementById('[Slip]Price Adjustment').focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've renamed the var  to several different things, I retyped the line of code. Not sure what to do....

Comment: share the minimal code producing this error. maybe you are missing something above or below the function

Comment: you need to show the code block, not this screenshot.

Comment: I added the entire function to the example.

Answer (score 0):

This error was solved by correcting the spelling of an HTML element involved with this function call.

Safari pointed to the correct error line.

Chrome would not point to the correct error line.

Answer (score -2):

Check opening and closing  curly braces {} on all functions of the page. Sometimes  {} mismatch ,also gives weird errors. Also try '' instead of "";

Comment: should be added as a comment

Comment: I change the '' to "" before posting this code. Both fail with this error.